# Way to cancel a signature request in Polkadot Extension

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-js

I hava an app that uses the polkadot extension to let the user sign requests. I am using the `signAndSend` method with the signer from the browser extension.

Is there a way to cancel a pending signature request programatically? I.e. the signature request popup is already open but then something happens (e.g. user clicks somewhere or navigates away) and I want to close it and cancel the request for signature?